# Mining a transaction with a 0 BTC output

Tags: non-standard-transaction, eligius

It is possible to mine tx that has a 0 BTC output?
In theory it is non-standard but valid, so it is not relayed but it can be mined.
How to mine it in practice? Are there nodes that accept it? I tried Eligius' 192.3.11.20 but it rejects it.

EDIT: i want to do p2pkh transaction

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to create `p2pkh` output and send zero satoshies on it? Such output is non-standard (dust) and will not be relayed and mined (but it is possible)

Or may be you want to create `nulldummy` (OP_RETURN) output? This is possible

BTW, sometimes miners confirm non-standard transactions, for example https://blockchain.info/tx/b4ea693a9d2d7e32b66777964fce13da302bed024bd9fd4651919da650fb1c40 (it is `p2pk` output)